# Include custom font in lightning components

Tags: lightning, static-resources, static, font

I am trying to include a custom font in my lightning components. Unfortunately I am not managing  in doing that. I uploaded a .eot file to my static resources and now I am trying to reference to it. Like this:

```
.THIS .font { 
     font-family: GothamBold;
}

@font-face {
     font-family:'GothamBold';
     src: "{!$Resource.B2B_Partners_GothamBold}";
}
```

I believe the src is the correct path, but what is going wrong? Or does anyone have a tip on how to include the font GothamBold in my lightning components. Or is there somewhere a tutorial on how to include a custom font as a static file in a lightning component?

Comment: you could start by checking if it is correct by looking at your browsers network tab using the dev tools

Comment: @glls Could you be a bit more specific maybe? Thanks

Comment: Google the last 10 words of my sentence.

Comment: This does not help me unfortunately. Do you have any other advice/examples on how to include a custom font as a static file in a lightning component?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uploading a .ttf file to my static resources and including it as follows worked for me:

```
.THIS .boldFont {
 font-family: GothamBold;
}

@font-face {
   font-family: GothamBold;
  src: url(/resource/B2B_Partners_GothamBold);
}
```

Comment: http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/06/22/custom-font-lightning-component-static-resource/

Answer (score 0):

This could help you even if you're kind of doing the right way:

http://www.minerva18.com/blog/using-custom-fonts-lightning-components/

The difference is the use of `local()` and `format()`.

Also the idea ( @glls ) to double check your browser network if font has been fetched is a good idea.

I haven't found documentation about expression in CSS file, maybe it is not supported. Then cf. @glls solution.

Edit: you should also try inline CSS in your markup, so you're sure expression works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but my font is not available at google fonts. So this wont work for me. Any other ideas?

Comment: What do you mean about Google font?

Comment: The video you shared shows how to include a font from google fonts. But the Font I need (GothamBold) is not on there. So I cant use the technique used in that video

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do to get it working was:

1. Save the font file (.ttf) as a static resource
2. Print/console log the URL for that font file using `{!$Resource.SalesforceSansRegular}` —SalesforceSansRegular being your static resource's name. You can print it by putting the expression in any part of your component— and then copy the outcome to clipboard.
3. In your CSS file just add the following code:

> ```
> @font-face {
>     font-family: 'SalesforceSans Regular';
>     src: url('/sfsites/c/resource/1500394667000/SalesforceSansRegular');
>     /*The URL that I am using here is the output of {!$Resource.SalesforceSansRegular}*/
> }
>
> .myFontClass {
>     font-family: 'Salesforce Regular';
> }
> ```

Just replace my URL with the one your `{!$Resource.SalesforceSansRegular}` returned